# Set jQuery selector on asp.net code behind variable in Content Page that comes from a Master Page control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an ASP LinkButton control that sits on the Master page. On one of the Content pages I want to set a scroll-to animation for that element when the user is brought to that page from a certain page.

What I want to do is dynamically set the jQuery selector based on a VB.net string variable (set from the ID of a control)

**ContentPage.aspx:**

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#<%= scrollToControl %>').offset().top + 'px'
}, 500, 'swing');
```

**ContentPage.aspx.vb**

```
Dim scrollToControl As String = CType(Master.FindControl("someControl"), LinkButton).ClientID
```

This is getting the ID, however when I try to update the ContentPage.aspx I get

`scrollToControl is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

*P.S Should I be adding the jQuery code entirely from the code behind rather than changing just the selector?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Dim`actually declares something as private.
Try declaring your string with `Protected` or `Public`.

```
Protected scrollToControl As String = CType(Master.FindControl("someControl"), LinkButton).ClientID
```

Hope that helps!

Also, concerning your P.S.: The way you do it or from codebehind using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` are both fine (imho). I think it's up to preference, I'd advise trying to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I just had to change the ordering a bit on the page - declare at the top and set in my page load function.